# Read-only file system error when try to install pod on macbook m1

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to install react-native app on ios emulator but i have an error  say it have no `podlock`, so i find solution here [No `Podfile' found in the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028286/no-podfile-found-in-the-project-directory)

but i ran into a problem when i try to `pod install` in ios folder, it show like this

[image]

Please help, i'm totally new to mac, i never using mac before, thank a lots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, it turns out this folder is read-only, don't know why but it was a document folder, I move the project to the top level of the document, like document/project, and it works, but place project in document/a/b/c/project it not work, so weird, still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some Libraries that break with pods with arm-64 MacBook pro's. I have faced the same issues while setting up with React-Native. You can duplicate your terminal and enable the open with the Rosseta option. This option will run the pods using the Rosetta emulation. There are still many libraries that break on the new MacBook Pro.

You can follow this link for adding a duplicate terminal that uses Rosetta: [Adding Rosseta Terminal](https://www.courier.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development)

Comment: Thank for your answer, but macos somehow so weird

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running `pod install` with the parameter `--project-direcotry=~/<path-to-my-project>` like this:

`pod install --project-directory=~/<path-to-my-project>`

Also, if you need to run `npx install-expo-modules`, could be achive by it:

`npx install-expo-modules ~/<path-to-my-project>`

Apparently, the simple fact to set relative path solved it ;)